# Register to a changed event on construction of Xdocument or XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

is there a a way to register to the changed event of the XDocument class, or the NodeChanged event of the XmlDocument class while the class is being constructed ?

the following code did not work for me (the handler was not called) :

```
string fileName = "MyFile.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.NodeChanged += new XmlNodeChangedEventHandler(xmlDocument_NodeChanged);
xmlDocument.Load(fileName);

 void xmlDocument_NodeChanged(object sender, XmlNodeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Comment: In what way didn't it work as expected? What happened? What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form MSDN,

> [XObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.changed.aspx) : Events are raised only when an XML tree is modified, not when it is constructed.

I couldn't find an equally pertinent statement for XmlDocument but it seems reasonable not to raise NodeChanged on creation. You might try NodeInserted.

### Update:

I just tried, NodeInserting and NodesInserted are firing during `Load()`.

Comment: Thanks, it works with the XmlDocument. i thought that the linq to xml (XDocument or XElement) supposed to have the same capabilities as the XmlDocument class. it will be more convenient  for me to the work with XDocument because obviously the rest of my application works with it :(

Comment: The way XDocument is designed (static Load and Parse methods) would make it very hard to attach a handler before reading.